# ASP.NET Ajax jquery input parameter is null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a problem with this.
below are my jquery code and aspx.cs code.
I should send `$('#UserID').val()` to WebMethod as a parameter.
but in WebMethod it is always null.
if I change `$('#UserID').val()` to `any string`, it works well.
`#UserID` is correct. because I made a alert window with this value.
and.. I already changed `data: '{userId: "' + $('#UserID').val() + '"}',` 
to `data: JSON.stringify({ userId: $('#UserID').val() })`.
but nothing works.

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "register.aspx/IsIdAvailable",
    type: "post",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: '{userId: "' + $('#UserID').val() + '"}',
    dataFilter: function (data) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(data);
        if (msg.hasOwnProperty('d'))
            return msg.d;
        else
            return msg;
    }
})
```

---

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool test(string userId)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("userId: " + userId +"!");
    ...
}
```

output is always `userId: !`

Comment: apparently `$('#UserID').val()` is null. Can you try this: `alert($('#UserID').val());` ?

Comment: Watch the network request in your browser debug console to see how it is posted to your server-side code.

Comment: You don't need the single quote. Change it to:  data: {userId : $('#UserID').val() },

Comment: I did everything you guys said. but it doesn't work. but thank you all.

Comment: You wrote `register.aspx/IsIdAvailable` in the script but `test` in C#. Is it a mistake in copy paste here?

Comment: sorry for confusing you. You're right. I made a mistake when I copy  paste here.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your data attribute to something like:

```
data: {'userId': $("#UserID").val()}
```